# What this means : Inconsistent accessibility: property type for localizing app in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have this error message:

Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Comm.Resources.AppResources' is less accessible than property 'Comm.Resources.LocalizedStrings.LocalizedResources'

I have done these :

```
1)) in App.xaml

< Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Comm.Resources"
            x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    </Application.Resources>



2) add this class LocalizedStrings in a Folder call Resources


namespace Comm.Resources
{
  public class LocalizedStrings
  {
    public LocalizedStrings()
    { }

            private static Comm.Resources.AppResources localizedResources = new Comm.Resources.AppResources();

            public Comm.Resources.AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return localizedResources; } }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means your `AppResources` is probably internal by default, but you're exposing it via a public property. Either make `AppResources` public (I'm not sure how to do that offhand, but the designer may well help you) or make the property internal.

Comment: Please help. I look at the designer but dont know where to start to edit. An exmple will be appreciated.

Comment: @MilkBottle: Well do you really *need* these to be public? Making the property internal may be simpler.

Comment: Good idea; How do I try this internal or declare internal. I had a go just now, I declared 1) private for (1) create resource , internal for LocalizedResources 2) Internal For (1) and internal for the LocalizedResource. Both are not working.

Comment: @MilkBottle: `internal Comm.Resources.AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return localizedResources; } }`

Comment: Skeed. Your 1st advice was good and I did not look carefully. It works after setting the access modifier to public. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Open AppResources.resx by double click in Solution Explorer. And please set "Access Modifier: Public".